# Password reset issue

Tags: pokemon-go

I'm using a trainers account to use Pokémon Go. I accidentally pressed "Sign Out", and now it won't accept my password. I've tried resetting it many times, but it won't accept my email as well. I'm sure that it's the right email, because I've recieved an email from Pokémon Go to verify it. It has happened to me before, and it accepted the password, but now it won't work.

Same error is coming up on my screen saying "Incorrect details. Try again after 15 minutes for security reasons."

Comment: Some things to check: 1. Make sure you're connected to the internet. 2. Make *sure* you're using the right password. I often have issues with passwords, I might miss a key, or accidentally press the wrong key when entering a password. 3. Make sure you're not under the effect of a [ban](http://www.theverge.com/2016/8/12/12461136/pokemon-go-niantic-permanent-game-ban-cheating-bots)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and read that I would have to use a laptop/desktop to reset. No you don't. When I got to the recover password page on my Android phone, in browser tools (where your refresh option is located), you want to click "request desktop site". It will load a while new page.

You will be able to recover it from there.